# Update CFLAGS or LDFLAGS in makefile depending on current OS

Tags: c++, macos, makefile

I'm trying to create a makefile that will works on both OSX and Linux.

My problem is I need to change `cflags` and `ldflags` depending on OS the makefile is executed but I can't make it work. That's my makefile :

```
OS:=$(shell uname)
DST=hello
SRC=$(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJ=$(SRC:.cpp=.o)
CFLAGS=

all: clean DetectOS $(DST)

DetectOS:
ifeq ($(OS),Darwin)
    @echo OS : $(OS)
    CC=g++
    LDFLAGS="-lm -framework OpenCL"
    CFLAGS+=-O3
endif

ifeq ($(OS),Linux)
    #Coming soon...
endif

$(DST): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -rf *.o $(DST)
```

But when I run this code, neither `cflags`, `ldflags` or `CC` are updated in the `ifeq` conditional block. I get the following result :

```
$ make
rm -rf *.o hello
OS : Darwin
CC=g++
LDFLAGS="-lm -framework OpenCL"
CFLAGS+=-O3
cc -o opencl.o -c opencl.cpp 
cc -o hello opencl.o 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:....
```

As you can see, the OS is detected because we went in the `ifeq` conditional block, but `CC` isn't updated and keep a non-initialized value of `cc`. Finally the linker process fails because OpenCL is not referenced in `ldflags`.

An other little point, if I don't put quotes in `LDFLAGS="-lm -framework OpenCL"` I get the error :

```
LDFLAGS=-lm -framework OpenCL
/bin/sh: -framework: command not found
make: *** [DetectOS] Error 127
```

And based on multiple exemples (here on stackoverflow) I should do it without quotes.

I'm currently on Mac OS X Yosemite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the ifeq block should not go into the make target, but just to the front of the makefile (before all:).

I.e. like this:

```
OS:=$(shell uname)
DST=hello
SRC=$(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJ=$(SRC:.cpp=.o)
CFLAGS=

ifeq ($(OS),Darwin)
    $(info OS is $(OS))
    CC=g++
    LDFLAGS=-lm -framework OpenCL
    CFLAGS+=-O3
endif

ifeq ($(OS),Linux)
    #Coming soon...
endif

all: clean $(DST)

...
```

(no "DetectOS" target, using info instead of echo)

Comment: With the `info` I get `makefile: commands commence before first target.` error, but if I remove it, it seems to work great, and that solved the quotes issue.

Comment: Hum maybe that is some incompatibility in the MacOs make, as the info command normally works in GNU make. Or maybe if there is a tab instead of spaces in front of $(info that could be the issue as well (tabs are sometimes kind of special in the makefile). You can also try to put the info statement outside the ifeq (before the block) without any spaces/tabs before.